# Как сделать событие на нажатие 4-ех клавиш (Ctrl + Shift + Alt + 1)?

Tags: python, tkinter

При использовании:

`widget.bind("<Control-Shift-Alt-1>", print)`

Ничего не происходит.
Как это реализовать с помощью tkinter?

Comment: но ведь `Q` — это уже `shift+q`. какой же тогда может быть смысл в комбинации `shift+Q` (`shift+shift+q`)?

Comment: Q - это для примера, клавиша может быть любой. Например, Control-Alt-Shift-1

Comment: ну вот я на основании вашего примера и спрашиваю: каким образом вы представляете себе нажатие клавиш `shift+shift+любая_клавиша`

Comment: root=Tk() root.bind('<Control-f>', тут Ваша функция)